# Is there anything like Wicket's ListView for GWT UIBinder?

Tags: gwt

Having used Wicket recently, I've come to really appreciate its `RepeatingView` and `ListView` objects.

They essentially allow you to specify the format of a "row" of data in an HTML template (which roughly corresponds to a UIBinder `Foo.gwt.xml`), and then in the corresponding Java class you loop over some data, which is then formatted and displayed according to the template.

The GWT version of this seems to require defining a brand new `Row.gwt.xml` template and Row.java class, which you then reference from the containing Foo.gwt.xml and Foo.java class.

Is there a way to do something like this in a single GWT UIBinder file/class, without creating a subsidiary `Row.gwt.xml` and `Row.java`?

Answer (score 0):

does this help ?

http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2008/09/04/wicket-and-gwt-compared-with-code/

Comment: Personal contact information can go in your [profile.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/648917/user648917)

Comment: yeah I know .. the "thing" is that I'm trying to reach George for a while but all I had was the elance private message system and now for some reasons I cannot access it anymore so that's why I put my "contact" info

Comment: Use the comment system to talk.  Don't put chat in your answer.